# View Helper Manager not accessible in Module Bootstrap using ZF3

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Using `Zend Framework 2` I can access the `ViewHelperManager` doing this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
   $viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewHelperManager');
}
```

This does not seem to work anymore in my Modules since starting a new project using `Zend Framework 3`.

Not quite sure what to do here.

Answer (score 6):

The Services are uppercased in Zend Framework 3 apparently.

```
$viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager');
var_dump(get_class($viewHelperManager));
```

returns `string(29) "Zend\View\HelperPluginManager"`