# How to custom title tag and meta tag description in ZF3?

Tags: zend-framework3

I'm using Zend Framework description and I'm trying to customize title tag like ZF2 documetation recommends, but I've got this error:

> Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   Unable to resolve service "viewHelperManager" to a factory; are you
>   certain you provided it during configuration? in
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:681
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(757):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->getFactory('viewHelperManag...')
>
> 1 /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(200):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('viewHelperManag...') #2
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/module/Stats/src/Module.php(43):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('viewHelperManag...') #3
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322):
>   Stats\Module->setLayoutTitle(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #4
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171):
>   Zend\EventManager\E in
>   /var/www/html/basketmetrics/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php
>   on line 681

This is my code on Module.php

```
namespace Stats;

class Module
{
    const VERSION = '3.0.2';

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e The MvcEvent instance
     * @return void
     */
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        // Register a render event
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setLayoutTitle'));
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e The MvcEvent instance
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLayoutTitle($e)
    {
        $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $action     = $matches->getParam('action');
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $module     = __NAMESPACE__;
        $siteName   = 'BasketMetrics';

        // Getting the view helper manager from the application service manager
        $viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewHelperManager');

        // Getting the headTitle helper from the view helper manager
        $headTitleHelper   = $viewHelperManager->get('headTitle');

        // Setting a separator string for segments
        $headTitleHelper->setSeparator(' - ');

        // Setting the action, controller, module and site name as title segments
        $headTitleHelper->append($action);
        $headTitleHelper->append($controller);
        $headTitleHelper->append($module);
        $headTitleHelper->append($siteName);
    }    

}
```

I don't know If I'm doing something wrong, or if I cannot do it like in ZF2.

And meta tag "description" how can I customize it?

Comment: "Unable to resolve service "viewHelperManager" to a factory" It's "ViewHelperManager" the "V" is capital.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View Helper Manager not accessible in Module Bootstrap using ZF3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186928/view-helper-manager-not-accessible-in-module-bootstrap-using-zf3)

Comment: it works!!! The "V" is capital!!!

Comment: Do you know how can I customize meta tag description?

Comment: How to customize? What do you want to do? Meta tag support really good. Did you check zend-view docs?

Answer (score 0):

->get('**V**iewHelperManager')
Up case